# Get a variable from Object Symbol

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object that when inspected by Developer Tools Console looks like this:

```
console.log("clicked: ", clickedMarker);
```

[image]

How can I get the `address` content form `Symbol(vars)`?

```
console.log("vars: ", clickedMarker["Symbol(vars)"]);
console.log("address: ", clickedMarker.address);
console.log("address2: ", clickedMarker["address"]);
console.log("vars2: ", clickedMarker["vars"]);
console.log("vars3: ", clickedMarker.vars);
console.log("Symbol(vars): ", clickedMarker._objectInstance["Symbol(vars)"]);
```

but it all comes out `undefined`.

**Edit:** This is a Typescript application but the Javascript solution worked fine.

Comment: Those are symbols, hence you need to look for them properly. If you don't know what a symbol is, please check the official MDN about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol . That said, here is a solution for your case, feel free to review or implement it in the way you like. https://jsfiddle.net/77fkrk7o/ . In a nutshell, you CAN'T search by string, you need to find the correct symbol through (eventually) a toString convertion.

Comment: Try this: console.log(clickedMarker.Marker._objectInstance); And produce the output please.

Comment: @briosheje Yep, that's it - it worked! Thank you!

Comment: @TadijaBagarić: I've added an answer below (for clarity reasons), feel free to review it, and don't remember to safely check whether mFound is undefined in your "Live" code to prevent undesired exceptions :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is likely that you are looking for a **string key** instead of a **symbol** one.

To read more about what a Symbol is (which is a primitive in javascript, anyway), please check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

To solve the issue, find the correct Symbol by using the comfortable **toString** prototype, and make use of the `getOwnPropertySymbols` method of the generic Object:

```
// look for the symbol having key "vars" in the object's symbols list.
var mFound = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(clickedMarker._objectInstance)
                   .find(e => e.toString() === "Symbol(vars)");
// Use the above symbol as the object's key.
var address = clickedMarker._objectInstance[mFound].address;
```

Please remember that, for further safety, you should check if `mFound` is effectively found (hence NOT undefined, or generically not falsey).

Comment: Regarding the undefined warning - If I explicitly set the the symbol is it possible for it to be falsey?

Comment: @TadijaBagarić : if no key for that symbol exists, it will return undefined. Hence you should (always) handle the undefined case, regardless it will or won't happen. I personally wouldn't force the symbol on that object specifically, I would only handle the case where no Symbol for "vars" is found. In a nutshell, I would simply add: `if (mFound) { // address stuff }`